# How install utils on colab?

Tags: python-import, google-colaboratory

How manually install util on google colab?

```
!pip install web.py==0.40.dev0
import utils
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a4c82eaa1619> in <module>()
     20 import torch.backends.cudnn
     21 get_ipython().system('pip install web.py==0.40.dev0')
---> 22 from Utils import *
     23 from PIL import Image
     24 from torch import nn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Utils'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to correct this mistake correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change to !pip install python-utils but

```
  Installing collected packages: python-utils
**Successfully installed python-utils-2.3.0**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e6796b5aa862> in <module>()
     20 import torch.backends.cudnn
     21 get_ipython().system('pip install python-utils')
---> 22 import utils
     23 from PIL import Image
     24 from torch import nn

ModuleNotFoundError: **No module named 'utils'**
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this if this may help in your code

!install pip
!pip install utils
import utils